# getting weird error while inserting image

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\floatbox%
    [{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={right,center},capbesidewidth=4cm}}]
    {%
      figure%
    }%
    [\FBwidth]
    {%
      \caption{\textbf Variation   of   average   grain   size   of   nanostructured NiFe2O4   with  milling  time.  The  continuous  line  is  guide  to the eye.}%
      \label{1fig}%
    }%
    {%
      \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{1fig.jpg}%
    }
\end{figure}
```

This is my code. I am getting weird error saying 'missing number, treated as zero'. How can I rectify it?

Comment: Show a complete example that can be used for tests. Replace the 1fig.jpg by a dummy e.g. example-image.

Comment: I agree with @Ulrike. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the problem is will be much easier. Have you loaded all the necessary packages, for example?